# Rails 3 resource routing without an id

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

I am creating a blog application on Rails 3, and I want to override the default show route generated for a post by doing

```
resources :posts, :except => :show
```

Which generates, for the show route (had I not excluded it),

```
/post/:id
```

I want my route to look like this instead, where url_title is a string generated by my model on before_save, where it removes non alphanumeric characters and replaces spaces with hyphens.

```
/:year/:month/:day/:url_title
```

I'm trying to accomplish this with this bit of code:

```
match "/:year/:month/:day/:url_title", :to => "posts#show", :as => :post
```

In theory this should allow me to call post_path(@post) (where @post is an instance of my post class), and it should be able to sort this route out, and it *almost* works.

The only problem is that it tries to substitute the id of the post in for the year. The other fields fill in correctly. I think this is happening because rails has some default behavior that makes it really, really want to have the id in the url, and it doesn't trust me to use my own unique identifier (post.url_title, in this case).

I could be wrong about that though. Anyone have experience with this kind of routing, or know what's up?

Comment: Have you verified that your routes look okay by using `rake routes` in terminal?

Comment: what does your posts controller look like?

Comment: Routes look like I expect in rake routes. My controller basically does, @post = Post.find_post_by_url(params[:url_title], Date.new(params[:year].to_i, params[:month].to_i, params[:day].to_i)).

My model then generates a query using that data and returns the post.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You can use to_param to craft the rails uses

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  ...
  def to_param
    "#{year}/#{month}/#{day}/#{title.parameterize}"
  end
end
```

More info: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Base.html#method-i-to_param and http://www.seoonrails.com/to_param-for-better-looking-urls.html

If you go this route, you'll want to create a permalink attribute, and use `Post.find_by_permalink(params[:id]`) rather than `Post.find(params[:id])`

Comment: Thanks, this looks exactly like what I want to do.

Comment: This looks great, but what do you put in config/routes.rb to make it work? I keep getting routing errors, even after restarting the server. Thanks.

Comment: @evanrmurphy it's normal "resources :whatevers"

Comment: @JesseWolgamott ended up solving my problem [using dynamic segments](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9266430/414220), thanks anyway.

Answer (score -2):

you should use path like this

```
post_path(@post, :year => 2010, :month => 3, :day => 16)
```

or

```
post_path(@post, :year => @post.created_at.year, :month => @post.created_at.month, :day => @post.created_at.day)
```

Comment: I can't try this until I get home, but I would prefer to just be able to pass in @post. Maybe I'm asking too much, but it's odd to me that rails can figure out the month and day by default but uses the id as the year.