# How to Use Rails 3 Routes with Dynamic Segments

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, routes, url-routing

In my Rails 3.2 application, there is an Exercise model with attributes muscle_group and grade_level. I've defined the following route with **dynamic segments** for it in config/routes.rb:

```
# config/routes.rb
match "/:muscle_group/grade-:grade_level/:id" => "exercises#show"
```

Running `bundle exec rake routes` confirms that the route does indeed exist:

```
/:muscle_group/grade-:grade_level/:id(.:format) exercises#show
```

The database contains an Exercise record with:

- id = 5
- muscle_group = "abdominal"
- grade_level = 1

And yet when I point my browser to http://localhost:3000/abdominal/grade-1/5, I get:

```
Routing Error
No route matches [GET] "/abdominal/grade-1/5"
Try running rake routes for more information on available routes.
```

How can I get this route with dynamic segments to work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The route declaration I was using was almost functional. For some reason there is an issue with using a hyphen and not having `grade_level` as its own `/`-separated substring. When I switched to using the route declaration:

```
match "/:muscle_group/grade/:grade_level/:id" => "exercises#show"
```

Instead of the original:

```
match "/:muscle_group/grade-:grade_level/:id" => "exercises#show"
```

http://localhost:3000/abdominal/grade/1/5 is then a valid route.

I would prefer to have this route with the hyphen and wish I knew how to make that work, but it is not a top priority. If anyone knows how to make it work with the hyphen, please let me know.

Answer (score 1):

Action pack in Rails uses the [to_param](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Base/to_param) to override how the urls get generated by the URL helpers. Take a look at this article, which explains it.

http://www.seoonrails.com/to_param-for-better-looking-urls.html

Comment: Also it seems like this other post is about a very similar thing.http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5326483/rails-3-resource-routing-without-an-id

Comment: I am trying it this way, overriding to_param to return `"#{muscle_group}/grade-#{grade_level}/#{id}"`. But what goes in `config/routes.rb` in this case?